# importerror no module named caches

Tags: python, ubuntu, gem5

I'm trying to run simulation by using gem5 on *ubuntu 16.04* lts
and I write code `'./build/X86/gem5.opt ./configs/tutorial/two_level.py'`.

The output on *terminal* was:

```
Traceback(most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "home/park/gem5/src/python/m5/main.py", line 433, in main
     exec filecode in scope
    File "./configs/tutorial/two_level.py", line 3, in <module>
     from caches import*
ImportError: No module named caches
```

I tried everything I can, but couldn't know. What is the problem?

Comment: I think you need to post some code. Read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

The file:

```
configs/tutorial/two_level.py
```

has never been part of the main tree according to:

```
git log -p -- '**/two_level.py'
```

so you must provide its source.

Supposing you are talking about `configs/learning_gem5/part1/two_level.py`, the problem is not reproducible on `master` at [da79d6c6cde0fbe5473ce868c9be4771160a003b](https://github.com/gem5/gem5/commit/da79d6c6cde0fbe5473ce868c9be4771160a003b) with the command:

```
./build/X86/gem5.opt configs/learning_gem5/part1/two_level.py
```

which appears to run correctly.